# Make sure number is entered in specific way in EditBox

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to make sure that numbers are entered into an EditBox in a specific format?
ie when someone types 11 it adds a . after it so if someone types 1124 it will recorrect when it gets to the end of the second 1 and adds a . making it 11.24. This is intended for currency. This is made for an TEdit
Thanks

Comment: Delphi doesn't have an `EditBox`. Do you mean a `TEdit`, `TMaskEdit`, or `TDBEdit`?

Comment: JediVCL might have few components on that. JvCalcEdit can be vioewed as MaskEdit with short-cut properties for numeric formats and built-in calculator. With JvValidateEdit you can - though it looks like misusing - make validation step analyzing for dot and adding it if missing. Personally i think that would be better that adding dot after 1st 2 digits. What if i wanted to ener "1234.56" and the stupid program added dot after just "12" ? I'd be infuriated. You can also do it in TEdit.OnExit event manually. Also DevExpress lib has some TcxCurrencyEdit control, but did not tried it.

Comment: @Arioch'The: None of the information you provided does anything to change the fact that Delphi **does not have** an `EditBox`, and until the poster edits to ask the real question, posting big blocks of text that don't apply to the question asked is just noise.

Comment: @Ken that's kind of nitpicking. TS did not told that Editbox is type name or some specific terms. You can argue that Delphi has no menu and no buttons, since they are called TMenu and TButton. I totally agree that the question is formulated very vague and hard to read. Still that does not mean there is no information that can be useful for TS.

Comment: @Arioch'The: But you've also started listing other third party components. Are we going to guess at every single control on the planet that contains the word `Edit` in it's classname? Of course not, so don't start trying. The poster should come back  and edit the question to ask about a real, existing component, and then we can answer questions about it. Trying to answer poor questions by guessing does nothing to help the quality of this site; ask for an edit to clarify instead, and wait for that to be done before answering. :-)

Comment: @Ken, he answered in the comments below that he meant TEdit. He did not updated the answer though :-(. And - even if he'd not specify - i'd read this as any Win32 TEdit-like control suffice. Like if he'd say button, i'd read it that any button would suffice. It would not mean that we must guess, it would mean that we are free to suggest any editbox that we feel suits the need. That was just a \*.\* mask :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a [`TMaskEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit.EditMask) for this; it's what it was designed to do.

```
MaskEdit1.EditMask := '00.00';  // requires two digits before and after
                                // the decimal point
```

See the documentation for [`TEditMask`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12309922/62576) for more information about the types of mask characters you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the "mask" property.  Check help.

Comment: Delphi doesn't have an `EditBox`, so it's very hard to find information about it in the help. You might want to either correct this to refer to an actual control (and provide a link to the documenation wiki which explains the mask property for it) or delete it. As it is right now, it's 100% wrong.

Comment: @Matt - truly, do edit your question. All the important information should be stated in questions, not somewhere deep in comments. Imagine someone would read this question 2 years into future. Why should he search all the comments ? You made an answer - good. But please also update the original question text to have that information as well.